# When the phone breaks and I regret encryption

Tags: encryption, android, iphone, data-recovery

I believe most new Android phones have full encryption enabled by default, so even if I just
download some PDF weather report from the internet, it will sit encrypted on my phone's SSD.

Now, suppose my phone breaks and loses power, such that just the SSD remains good and I eventually
get all of the SSD's raw bits copied into a file on my computer.

Then, in principle, with a lot of research into Android's encryption methods and knowledge of my
broken phone's password, I should be able to unencrypt those copied bits and ultimately see that
weather report as proof.  (By design, without the password, the bits can never be decrypted.
By the way, let me group fingerprint, facial recognition, and PIN authentication measures within
the term "password" for simplicity here.)

But, in practice, I highly doubt anyone would recover a phone's data like that.  So, what should
I do if I have some valuable million-dollar encrypted file on a broken phone?  To be specific,
assume the phone is a Google Pixel 6 Pro.  Notice that this is different from the FBI's problem
because I have the password.

I am also curious, do any phone makers provide some proactive means to anticipate recovery like
this (e.g., "Download Your Decryption Key" in Android Settings, though this would not normally
be recommended since this key is ideally never saved anywhere and ideally just reassembled from
the password at each use)?

Comment: *" what should I do if I have some valuable million-dollar encrypted file on a broken phone?"*  - in a way you are constructing a case where you have valuable data but did not bother to backup these. You just were lucky that the SSD is still somehow working even if the phone is broken. Apart from that it is not clear how broken it is - just the display, i.e. it can be switched on? Or it cannot even be switched on anymore? *" do any phone makers provide some proactive means to anticipate recovery"* - its called a backup. And it works even if the disk is broken too.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich "Just the SSD remains good" means that everything else is broken.  And, yes, of course, I know I can backup files on my own, but was just curious if I can be even lazier.

Comment: You can also replace "when the phone breaks" with "lost or stolen phone" in the sentence. In such a scenario encryption is more a blessing than a curse if you have sensitive/valuable files on the device.

Comment: Android & iOS storage encryption is designed to be volatile. Its keys cannot be cloned & migrated. Android cloud backups are end-to-end-encrypted and it's the closest solution for your usecase.

Comment: I'll add this is the case with a lot of laptops now also. For instance Apple laptops have always-on encryption with their SSDs. The SSDs are built in to the laptop motherboards, so the storage is not separable like older laptops. So if one different part of the laptop breaks, you can't reasonably access the storage. And on top of that, required encryption keys are stored in other components of the motherboard. So even if you could access the storage apart from the rest of the laptop, you would be out of luck. These encryption schemes for data storage are definitely not designed to be portable.